# How to keep track of pthread C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm new in pthread and I'd like to traverse directories using pthread. In my handling function,I'd like to create a new pthread and pass the same handling function to it whenever a directory is found.

**My question is how to keep track of all the pthreads and know how many pthreads have been created so that I can `join()` all threads?**

Can I declare `pthread_t* threads` and `int* number_of_threads` globally and malloc a space on heap in the main?

Or is it better to use struct which contains `pthread_t* threads` and `int* number_of_threads` and pass it to each new pthread?

I know that it is better to traverse directory without using pthread but it was required using pthread in my assignment...

Comment: If you don't know how many you created, chances are your threading model is hosed anyway. Identify where they're to be created, how long they should live, and when/who should know when they are expected to finish and be joined. Without that you're literally starting pthread programming in reverse.

Comment: @WhozCraig is right, "create a new pthread  ...  whenever a directory is found" doesn't work. In any situation where multiprocessing would really help directory traversal, the number of threads necessary would too easily surpass reasonable limits.  pthreads are light weigh only in comparison to complete processes - running thousands of them still requires huge volumes of context switching between threads, though much less than processes. You want a pool of a small, static number of threads to handle a queue of directories to traverse. They can add the subdirectories they discover to the queue.

Comment: @WhozCraig According to our professor, he said "step one is to create a bunch of pthread and step two is join() all threads we just created", which does't make sense to me. Because the handling function is called recursively, how can we create a bunch of unknown number of pthreads

Comment: It does make sense. I'm on another question, but I'll try and explain what he's referring to. The recursion is being half-replaced with threading. It's not a great design, but I understand what he's going after.